# Scraping answers from Quora question only returns 10 answers

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, quora

I am trying to scrape all the answers from a Quora question like this

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://www.quora.com/What-is-it-like-to-live-in-London'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
answers = soup.find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"})
data = json.loads(answers.string)
len(data["mainEntity"]["suggestedAnswer"])
```

However when I check the length of the suggestedAnswer, I am only getting 10 items. It appears that these 10 items are filtered by using the  soup.find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"}) . Is there a way to get all the answers?

Comment: Yes because 10+ answers are loaded dynamically when user scrolls to the position.You can look into https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ .   You can simulate user actions with this and get the data using bs4

Comment: But when I take a look at the soup it does look that all of the answers appear, just not sure how to retrieve them

Comment: You sure? It looks like only 10 answers to me.

Comment: @venky__ is right..There are only 10 answers...I don't think this can be done with `requests` . Might need `selenium` for this.

Comment: Before I filter by script type yes, I made sure that in the whole soup the very bottom posts appear, but for some reason they don't in the "answers".

Comment: As others have mentioned, in order to extract more than 10 answers you will have to simulate a human-like input, which can only be done by automation such as selenium. I don't think there's any other way for this kind of problem.